# What happened to the edit links in the Page Manager UI?

Tags: panels

I uploaded a site to a shared hosting environment and suddenly I can't use the *edit* links in the Page Manager UI any more.  As you can see in the screenshot, they've simply disappeared.  I can click the triangle and get a *disable* link but no *edit*.

I cleared the cache multiple times to no effect.  I then made a database dump of the server mysql and imported it into a local copy and experienced the same problem, even after clearing the cache multiple times.  I then turned off all of the aggregation options on the **Performance** configuration page and cleared the cache again, but no change.

Is this a typical problem or something I have uniquely done to screw things up?

[image: page manager UI glitch]

EDIT: Upon further inspection, I noticed something else weird.  I am able to access the pages by typing in the URL manually, but when I go to edit a piece of custom content, the *Edit* option, which is usually just under *Disable this pane*, is missing:

[image: no edit link]

Comment: can you access the page edit by typing the url in the browser directly?

Comment: @Aboodred1 Yes. Good point. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem-- I had been lazy and replaced the "Edit" translation string with a space to remove it from some of the pages on the site, forgetting that it would remove "Edit" from all pages on the site.  Restoring the string fixed the problem.